# Get selected value to another field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for tag selection, And what i want to do with this is i need to show some more details of the selected tag in anothe field[image]

```js
$.getJSON( /*[[@{/product/list}]]*/ 'http://localhost:8080/product/list', function(data) {
  product = data;
  ms1 = $('#ms1').tagSuggest({
    data: product[0],
    sortOrder: 'name',
    maxDropHeight: 200,
    name: 'ms1'
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="ms1" class="form-control" name="ms1" />
```

how can i implement it using tagsuggest plugin?

Comment: ok but what is your question?

Comment: Return more info about the tag in your response array `data`. And once that is got selected pull other info for the tag and show in your HTML.

Comment: @nem how can i implement it using tagsuggest plugin?

Comment: @deepakb `[['apple'],[2]]` .... response data is something like this

Comment: `[['apple', 'more info about apple'], [2, 'more info about 2']]` - Make your array like this.

Comment: Can you provide the link to tagsuggest plugin? There must be a callback for that where you can add your code to show extra info!

Comment: @deepakb https://remysharp.com/2007/12/28/jquery-tag-suggestion